# Android Studio Google Maps Emulator stuck on location?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-maps

I am a new learner in Java. As the title describes, I can't roam freely on google maps in the emulator PIXEL 2 API 29. The camera is stuck in the center of the location and no matter what I can't get the camera to elsewhere. I dont think it is the API cuz I have tested it without the code. Open to the suggestions, thank you. here is the code;

`

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    LocationManager locationManager;
    LocationListener locationListener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(@NonNull Location location) {
                LatLng userLocation = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(userLocation,15));
                System.out.println("location: " + location);


            }
        };

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            if(checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                requestPermissions(new String[] {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},1);
            } else {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0,0,locationListener);

            }
        }else {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0,0,locationListener);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if(grantResults.length> 0){
            if(requestCode==1){
                if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0,0,locationListener);
                }
            }
        }

    }
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the function `onLocationChanged()` of `LocationLister` in your code moves the camera to the current location of your device that gets triggered whenever the center of the map is not in the current location of the device.

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
   LatLng userLocation = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());
   mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(userLocation,15));
   System.out.println("location: " + location);
}
```

`LocationListener` location is registered through the location manager service using the `locationManager.requestLocationUpdates()`. To learn more please see the [documentation here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener).

If your main goal is to get the current device location and display it on the map as it loads, there is an official documentation from Google Maps Platform to guide you on how to do it. To get you started, you can check it [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/location).

Comment: I'll check it out right now. Thank you for your feedback man